# Multiple messages in a tcp buffer

Tags: c++, tcp

I am actually programming a simple server and it's client in c++ using the tcp protocol. As this is to be integrated in a multiplayer game, every client has to send data extremely fast.

Issue: The server's buffer sometimes gets multiple messages in it.

I tried various things like putting off nagle's algorithm but I didn't manage to fix this problem. Here's the server's code :

```
    #ifdef __linux__
    #include <sys/types.h>
    #include <sys/socket.h>
    #include <netinet/in.h>
    #include <netinet/ip.h>
    #include <netinet/tcp.h>
    #include <unistd.h>
    #include <stdlib.h>
    #include <string.h>
    #include <fcntl.h>
    #include <errno.h>
    #include <arpa/inet.h>
    #define SOCKET int
    #define SOCKADDR_IN struct sockaddr_in
#endif
#ifdef _WIN32
    #include <winsock2.h>
#endif
#include <cstdio>
#include <iostream>
#include <thread>
#include <vector>
#include <string>
#include "server.h"
#include "../../Logger/logger.h"
#include "../../AltisCraft.fr/Map/map.h"
#include "../../StringPlus/string_plus.h"
#include "../../AltisCraft.fr/Map/User/User.h"
void connectEvent(), receive(), sendAllUsers(string), closeConnectio(),manageMsg();
vector<SOCKET> clients;
vector<thread> clientsThreads;
vector<string> msg;
SOCKET socketId, newSocketId;
SOCKADDR_IN source;
thread connection;
char buffer[65535] = {0};
int position;

// TODO: crypt every data sendLog/receive
// TODO: whitelist ip serv
// TODO: Auth system
// TODO: timer with packet ? (double receive...)

int sendLog(SOCKET s, const char* c, int i0, int i1)
{
    log("Send:");
    log(c);
    send(s, c, i0, i1);
}

void initializeNetwork()
{
    #ifdef _WIN32
        WSADATA initWin32;
        WSAStartup(MAKEWORD(2, 2),&initWin32);
    #endif
    socketId = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
    source.sin_family = AF_INET;
    source.sin_addr.s_addr = INADDR_ANY;
    source.sin_port = htons(33333);
    bind(socketId, (struct sockaddr*)&source, sizeof(source));
    connection = thread(&connectEvent);
    connection.join();
    closeConnection();
}

void connectEvent()
{
    int error;
    while(1)
    {
        error = 99;
        while(error != 0)
        {
            error = listen(socketId, 1);
        }
        #ifdef _WIN32
            int tempo = sizeof(source);
            newSocketId = accept(socketId, (struct sockaddr*)&source, &tempo);
            clients.push_back(newSocketId);
        #endif
        #ifdef __linux__
            socklen_t tempo;
            newSocketId = accept(socketId, (struct sockaddr *)&source, &tempo);
            clients.push_back(newSocketId);
        #endif
        clientsThreads.push_back(thread(&receive));
    }
}

void receive()
{
    int val = 1;
    position = clients.size() - 1;
    bool connected = 1;
    while(connected)
    {
        buffer[65535] = {0};
        if(recv(clients[position], buffer, 1515, 0) > 0)
        {
            string msg = buffer;
            bool isEmpty = false;
            log(string(inet_ntoa(source.sin_addr)) + ": " + msg);
            if(startsWith(msg, "Connect "))
                addUser(replace(msg, "Connect ", ""));
            else if(msg == "MAJ Map")
            {
                log(elements);
                string toSend = "MAJ Map\n" + elements;
                sendLog(clients[position], toSend.c_str(), strlen(toSend.c_str()), 0);
            }
            else if(startsWith(msg, "MAJ User ")) /// optimize: don't sendLog pos to player who sendLog
            {
                msg = replace(msg, "MAJ User ", "");
                if(startsWith(msg, "Pos "))
                {
                    msg = replace(msg, "Pos ", "");
                    vector<string> elements = split(msg, " ");
                    User user = *getUserByName(elements[0] + " " + elements[1]);
                    user.updateView(user.getView().updatePosition(Position(convertStrToDouble(elements[2]), convertStrToDouble(elements[3]), convertStrToDouble(elements[4]))));
                }
                else if(startsWith(msg, "ViewAngle "))
                {
                    msg = replace(msg, "ViewAngle ", "");
                    vector<string> elements = split(msg, " ");
                    User user = *getUserByName(elements[0] + " " + elements[1]);
                    user.updateView(user.getView().updateViewAngle(ViewAngle(convertStrToDouble(elements[2]), convertStrToDouble(elements[3]))));
                }
            }
            else
                sendAllUsers(string(string(inet_ntoa(source.sin_addr)) + ": " + msg).c_str());
        }
        else
            connected = 0;
    }
    shutdown(clients[position], 2);
    for(int i=0;i<msg.size();i++)
        cout << msg[i] << endl;
    #ifdef _WIN32
        closesocket(clients[position]);
    #endif
    #ifdef __linux__
        close(clients[position]);
    #endif
    clients.erase(clients.begin() + position);

}


void sendAllUsersWithoutOne(string msg, string name)
{
    for(int j = 0; j < (int)clients.size(); j++)
    {
        // only linux here (MSG_DONTWAIT)
        #ifdef __linux__
        if(recv(clients[j], NULL, 1, MSG_PEEK | MSG_DONTWAIT) == 0)
        {
            clients.erase(clients.begin() + j);
            continue;
        }
        #endif
        sendLog(clients[j], msg.c_str(), strlen(msg.c_str()), 0);
    }
}

void sendAllUsers(string msg)
{
    for(int j = 0; j < (int)clients.size(); j++)
    {
        // only linux here (MSG_DONTWAIT)
        #ifdef __linux__
        if(recv(clients[j], NULL, 1, MSG_PEEK | MSG_DONTWAIT) == 0)
        {
            clients.erase(clients.begin() + j);
            continue;
        }
        #endif
        sendLog(clients[j], msg.c_str(), strlen(msg.c_str()), 0);
    }
}

void closeConnection()
{
    for(int i = 0; i < (int)clients.size(); i++)
    {
        shutdown(clients[i], 2);
        #ifdef _WIN32
            closesocket(clients[i]);
        #endif
        #ifdef __linux__
            close(clients[i]);
        #endif
    }
    #ifdef _WIN32
        closesocket(socketId);
        WSACleanup();
    #endif
    #ifdef __linux__
        close(socketId);
    #endif
}

void freeNetwork()
{
    closeConnection();
}`
```

Comment: Ummmm.... You forgot to put the problem.

Comment: @Error - Syntactical Remorse I put it in bold.

Comment: First of all you shouldn't be using TCP if you need to send/receive data extremely fast - try UDP. If you have multiple messages in the buffer you should try reading from the buffer until it's empty - another thing is that you should also be prepared that your buffer may contain only a part of the message in that case you won't be able to read the message until the rest of it is received. You should also consider using non blocking sockets and/or microthreads vel coroutines.

Comment: TCP doesn't know anything about message boundaries, it's a simple byte stream. You need to implement something in your application code that detects message boundaries. For instance, you can send the message size first. Then the server can read the size bytes and then read just that many data bytes, so it won't get anything from the next message.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

to expand on Barmar's comment

TCP is a streaming protocol, not a message protocol. THe only guarantee is that you send n bytes, you will receive n bytes in the same order.

You might `send` 1 chunk of 100 bytes and receive 100 1 byte `recv`s, or you might receive 20 5 bytes `recv`s

You could send 100 1 byte chunks and receive 4 25 byte messages

You must deal with message boundaries yourself. Either have a sentinel value to mark start and end or prepend a length that is a fixed size itself (so you know you have read the whole length). Then loop on `recv` till you have received the whole message